Did Willa Cather plagiarize her acclaimed 1928, Death Comes For The Archbishop, from a 1908 biography by William J. Howlett?
Did Willa Cather plagiarize her acclaimed 1928 novel, Death Comes For The Archbishop? She acknowledged to have been influenced by a biography published in 1908 and written by the Rev. W.J. Howlett: Life of the Right reverend Joseph P. Macheboeuf, D.D.
While checking details of the biography, I was struck by the similarities between two passages:

Cather - How joyfully Father Joseph had written all this to his sister
Philomène, then a pupil with the nuns of the Visitation in their
native Riom, begging her to make him a quantity of artificial flowers
for his May altar.


Howlett - Immediately he wrote to his young sister, who was a pupil
with the nuns of the Visitation in his native village of Riom,
expressing his lively joy and requesting her to make up and send to
him at once a supply of artificial flowers for his May altar

I found a digitized copy of the latter, which unfortunately is riddled with digitization errors; it took me some work to obtain an improved text version.
Asking around, an expert in contemporary-literature plagiarism suggested to use Wcopyfind for the analysis. After cleaning up Cather's text for the comparison, and obtaining this file version, I tried to run  Wcopyfind. However, due to my ignorance and inexperience at running comparisons, I didn't obtain meaningful results. Any help would be appreciated.
Does anybody here know how to run Wcopyfind please?

Clearly the paragraph that you quoted was copied (with minor alterations) from Howlett, so could you clarify exactly what you're asking here? Are you trying to find more examples of copying? Or are you trying to compute an estimate of the proportion of copied text?

In a fiction acknowledged to be based on real events, is it really fair to call a retelling of one of those events in the authors own words "plagiarism"?

@DJClayworth, the whole story by Cather is parallel to the biography written by author Howlett. Several passages are almost verbatim; the one I reported in my question is just an example.

@GarethRees, yes I'd like to compute some parameter that would be useful to a copyright expert, or to a scholar that looks at these type of comparisons, and further instances of quasi verbatim copying.

Picking up parallels between these two texts is not new apparently. In their 1955 piece "The Genesis of Death Comes for the Archbishop (American Literature vol 26.4, pp. 479-506), Lillian Bloom and Edward Bloom are writing about Cather's use of Howlett's text and claim "that a comparison between the two books makes impressive the large number of details, incidents, and psychological qualities which she borrowed." (494) They then continue with longish tables that present story elements as well as individual passages side by side.

This seems a good one, thanks! I won't need to run Wcopyfind.
